# Wrapping image url in typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I used the typoscript below, only the image is not wrapped in `<img src="|" class="tip-image" alt="">`, it only generates the image url. Out is shown below. What do I wrong?

```
  tipmenu = HMENU
  tipmenu.special = directory
  tipmenu.special.value = 8
  tipmenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      wrap = <div class="left_links">|</div>

      NO {

        stdWrap.cObject = COA 
        stdWrap.cObject { 

          10 = FILES
          10 {
            references {
              data = levelmedia:-1, slide
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
              10 = IMG_RESOURCE
              10 {
                file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                file.maxW = 50
                file.maxH = 50
              }
            }
          }
          10.wrap = <img src="|" class="tip-image" alt="">


          20 = TEXT 
          20.field = title 
          20.wrap = <span class="tip-title">|</span>

          30 = TEXT 
          30.field = subtitle 
          30.wrap = <span class="tip-subtitle">|</span>    

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hereby the html output:

```
<div class="left_links">
   <a href="tips/verhalen-van-klanten/">
      fileadmin/_processed_/csm_klanten_e92ee310e0.png
      <span class="tip-title">Verhalen van klanten</span>
      <span class="tip-subtitle">Wat vind jij?</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FILES](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html) has no wrap. Use your wrap inside a stdWrap.

```
10.stdWrap.wrap = <img src="|" class="tip-image" alt="">
```

Some hints:

Maybe you should add a maxItems = 1 inside Files. If an editor inserts two or more images the output would look like this: `<img src="image1.jpgimage2jpgimage3.jpg" class="tip-image" alt="">`

You do not need the COA. Use the IMG_RESOURCE directly unless there is a reason for the COA.

```
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj {
        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        file.maxW = 50
        file.maxH = 50
    }
```